# How to query customer idcardno and passport from select as query to be idcardno/passport in PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql

Currently, I encounter with the '/' issue.
Example, I would like to select customer idcardno and passport from table. But actually idcardno and passport are in the same column as idcardno.

In my requirement, I would like the query to be "Idcardno/Passport",
ex: select idcardno as idcardno/Passport, * from customer

But couldn't any help on google, also always got an error this line.
May I ask that Is it possible in programming like this?

Can anyone help me on this?
would be very appreciate with your answer.

Thank you very much.

Comment: That is a bit unclear. Can you describe it more clearly, maybe with an example?

Comment: If you just want to rename your field you have to surround with " : select idcardno as "idcardno/Passport", * from customer

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe now I want to query idcardno column which contains idacrd and passport information. But the in the idcardno column, after I query then I would like to add "/Pasport"  in the back end. 

For Ex: select idcardno as idcardno/passport from customer.
But got an error at the "/".
So are there any help on this?

Thank you very much,

Comment: @RémyBaron, I have tried several times, many style as your opinion but still not pass the error.

Thanks,

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thank you very much sir. Now GurV already fix it. However, thanks for your comment. I will do my best next times.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to alias the `idcardno` as `idcardno/Passport`, use `"` to wrap the alias

```
select
  idcardno as "idcardno/Passport",
  c.*
from customer c
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir.
You fix my problem, thanks.

Comment: @Som [Glad I could help.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121597/how-can-i-show-my-appreciation-for-someones-time-taken-to-answer-my-question)